# Why Json Unmarshall changing array type in Golang?

Tags: go, unmarshalling

I'm trying to seed my Postgres database as functionally. In my case, SeedSchema() function can take any type struct. So I define a interface and create functions to my structs which will seed. I tried with generics and without.

When I unmarshall any json array from file as byte array, json.Unmarshall method change my tempMember member of struct. Exp, models.Term to map[string]interface{}. I've used unmarshall before this function and I've not seen like this situation.

Here is my SeedSchema() function:

```
func (db *Database) SeedSchema(models ...globals.Seeder[any]) error {
var (
    subjects []globals.Seeder[any]
    fileByte []byte
    err      error
    // tempMember any
)
if len(models) == 0 {
    subjects = seederModelList
} else {
    subjects = models
}
for _, model := range subjects {
    fileName, tempMember := model.Seed()
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", reflect.TypeOf(tempMember)) //1
    if fileByte, err = os.ReadFile("db/seeds/" + fileName); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return err
    }
    if err = json.Unmarshal(fileByte, &tempMember); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return err
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", reflect.TypeOf(tempMember)) //2

}
return nil 
}
```

First print returns []models.AirportCodes and the second []interface {}.

Here is my interface and model:

```
func (AirportCodes) Seed() (string, any) {
    return "airport_codes.json", []AirportCodes{}
}

type Seeder[T any] interface {
    Seed() (string, T)
    // Seed(*gorm.DB) error
    TableName() string
}

seederModelList = []globals.Seeder[any]{
        m.AirportCodes{},
        m.Term{},
    }
```

Comment: JSON marshaling does not transfer Go type information. If the type you unmarshal into does not specify types, the `encoding/json` package will choose types to unmarshal into, e.g. `string` for JSON strings, `float64` for JSON numbers etc.

Comment: But type can any struct, I must do that dynamic. I cant define again in functions the elements.  Isn't it purpose of Interface that?

Comment: Again: Go type information is not transfered. How do you expect `encoding/json` to find out what struct type to use?

Comment: So, I must modify UnmarshallerJson interface for Seeder interface ?

Comment: Yes, if by modify you mean implement, create one for each type of seeder you need. Should also compose the `Seeder[T]` definition with `json.Unmarshaler`. The reason you aren't getting the same seeder is because you're using `Seeder[any]`. By default this will unmarshal every `T` into an `interface{}`. You could also use a closure to return a type-specific unmarshaler based on the `fileName` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few weeks, I have looking for solve this problem and look unmarshaler interfaces and examples. Then Like what [icza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1705598/icza) said, I started to look over the my code that convention between types and I solved like this. If you guys have better answer than mine, please add answer.

Data:

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "name":"Term 1",
        "content": [
            "a1",
            "a2",
            "a3"
        ]
    }
]
```

Result:

```
[{ID:1 Name:Term 1 Content:[a1 a2 a3]}]
```

UnmarshalJSON Function:

```
func (term *Term) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    tempMap := map[string]interface{}{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &tempMap); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *term = Term{
        Name: tempMap["name"].(string),
    }
    if tempMap["content"] != nil {
        for _, v := range tempMap["content"].([]interface{}) {
            (*term).Content = append((term).Content, v.(string))
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Thank you for comments.